# Dump a log message from tortoise svn to a file using TortoiseProc.exe

Tags: perl, svn, tortoisesvn

I was trying to create a script that could parse the log for a particular revision in svn and get details from that log like the author name, the underlying paths affected and the actions performed. I am trying to use the following command in perl with backticks:

> `TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path:"$svn_path" /startrev:"$svn_rev" /endrev:"$svn_rev" /outfile:$file`;

for the outfile option it's been specified as /outfile:path\to\file. I've tried so many combinations to get the syntax right but the log file is not getting created. I tried to do

> /outfile:D:\other\to\filename.txt

I even tried putting only filename there thinking it'd be created in the same directory, tried only giving the path and even tried creating the file myself waiting for it to write to. Nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know that svnlook command can be used but I don't have the commandline interface installed. If it is it would be great if anyone could help me out with dumping the svnlook output to a file. But the priority is working with TortoiseProc.exe

Answer (score 1):

The backslash in Perl and in most of shells needs to be properly qouted.

Check the cmd.log file and tune the amount of backslashes until it is working

```
my $file = "D:\\\\other\\\\to\\\\filename.txt";
open my $fh,'>','cmd.log' or die $!;
print $fh "TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path:\"$svn_path\" /startrev:\"$svn_rev\" /endrev:\"$svn_rev\" /outfile:\"$file\"\r\n";
close($fh);
my $out = `TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path:"$svn_path" /startrev:"$svn_rev" /endrev:"$svn_rev" /outfile:"$file"`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `outfile` argument only works if you are using a nightly build of TortoiseSVN. See [here](http://tigris-scm.10930.n7.nabble.com/outfile-working-example-please-td12058.html)

An alternative might be to use svn.exe, which also comes with TortoiseSVN, in the following way:

```
svn.exe log -v -r 111041 >output.txt
```